# Azure MFA implementation without opening a browser

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I want to implement MFA for authenticating an Azure Active Directory account in .NET code without having to use a browser. Is there any library which can be used for this? Available ADAL library methods (Authorization code flow & device code flow both need browser to be opened somewhere) doesn't allow implementation of MFA without opening a browser.

Answer (score 2):

MFA is always done in the browser page. This can be via a redirect, pop-up, or the browser view can be embedded in your app (depends on your app type).

Comment: more correct to say, some apps  WebBrowser *control*  wrapped in a regular app window, which is, technically, still a browser

Comment: Are you referring to a non-interactive (standard MS) flow? If so would that be limited to just a B2C tenant? My question is here incase this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899275/azure-active-directory-user-flow-for-authentication-mfa-without-b2c