# Does Azure provide any capability to programmatically login, reset password or device authenticate like AWS Cognito?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web app that has a group of users in Azure AD and I'd like to authenticate against that via username/password but customize the solution with my own styled login screen and have device authentication similar to how AWS Cognito has the OTP/MFA.

User flow I seek:

1. User goes to my website
2. I provide my own login form
3. Said form would theoretically use the same functionality that AWS Cognito provides to login programmatically with no microsoft flow or redirects
4. Either using Azure capabilities/API or my own, I do a device authentication for MFA

So, looking at the list of flows provided:

[image: Kindly taken from Microsoft DevRadio's youtube video]

What are the possible flows that I can use to accomplish what I need?

1. The username/password "password" grant only works if MFA is disabled, so one scenario I can envision is possible combining this with my own code that does MFA (and possibly using MS Authenticator). It also doesn't seemingly work for resetting passwords.
2. The interactive flow is the standard flow and would show the default MS page along with MFA but it wouldn't be customizeable
3. Would a custom flow be possible, or a device code flow and would this be limited to just a B2C tenant?
4. Is it possible to setup Azure AD as a federated identity and hook into Cognito's methods to do this? I assume not because authentication needs to be against the original identity provider and it seems like it can only work the reverse (a cognito user gets access to Azure).

It seems like the only possible solution would be using Azure's ROPC with a username/password password grant API endpoint combined with my own device authentication, but this wouldn't account for password resetting nor does it seemingly provide any api device auth methods?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Customizing login page in Azure AD (not B2C) is currently limited to [Branding update](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding). But that is available only in Premium tier.

You can upvote the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39419713).

Another option is [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) with your own page but Microsoft recommends **NOT** to use ROPC flow. Also MFA would not work in ROPC.

When you said "The username/password "password" grant only works if MFA is enabled", not sure if I could follow that! Can you explain?

And, custom user flow is only limited to B2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/

Comment: Correction: I meant that it only works if MFA is disabled, otherwise you get a message stating that it won't work because of MFA; I believe I was referring to ROPC.

Comment: Is it common/possible to convert to B2C and are there reprecussions if you were to convert? What are the solutions available in B2C specifically for that solution and do they include an endpoint you can use to manually trigger a device code to be sent and implement your own code to validate it, etc? Basically copy the same flow that Microsoft offers in Interactive but to your own solution?

Comment: B2C supports MFA like regular AAD. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-multi-factor-authentication. Question is how much important customizing the login page is to you? That (white-labeling) is one of the many use cases of [B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to use Azure B2C ?an alternative which offers more flexibility would be to use FusionAuth open source or Keycloak and setup open ID with Azure AD.

FusionAuth setup with Azure AD

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/identity-providers/openid-connect/azure-ad

Keycloak

https://suryaprakash-pandey.medium.com/azure-ad-idp-with-keycloak-as-sp-1ca933d71388

Comment: Is there an overall/eventual user flow gif/diagram of how it works after setting those up? " Now if you application is configured with keycloak properly, you will be able to redirect to Microsoft login page on hit of your application URL." seems like it's the same flow I already have unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Normally yes for this flow. It seems you want something like native app authentication using username and password? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768576/connect-to-azure-ad-using-username-password if you want to avoid getting redirected to microsoft page.

Comment: I guess you can use AWS Cognito custom flow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html and put the native app authentication using Resource Owner in the Lambda but it is not very recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you could login to Azure using Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-5.5.0 `Connect-AzAccount`
You could also run a Powershell script from within PHP, so maybe run a Powershell script to get the information from Azure and then process them in your PHP ?

Comment: Would this cover things like password resetting, or would MFA work besides just login?

Comment: "Azure AD v2 (for Graph) PowerShell. Supports Azure MFA with Connect-AzureAD" : https://365adviser.com/office-365/securely-connect-office-365-azure-ad-using-powershell-mfa/  password reset  do not know but see this https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-howitworks if it works for you ?

Comment: https://www.thelazyadministrator.com/2019/02/05/powershell-function-to-connect-to-all-office-365-services-with-support-for-mfa/